# Spring Boot: Get JSON body when RESTFul error (404, 403, 500) occurs

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am creating an application which calls a RESTful endpoint (via a GET method), of which if the response is Status code 200, it returns a JSON containing useful data.

This is achieved by the following line:

```
ResponseEntity<CorrectResponseObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, CorrectResponseObject.class);
```

However, if I hit the URL with a status code other than 200 (e.g. 403, 404), a different JSON is retrieved when using POSTman:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1505383198800,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
    "message": "Access is denied",
    "path": "/api/test/client/abcd"
}
```

But after my Java program executes the following line:

```
ResponseEntity<CorrectResponseObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, CorrectResponseObject.class);
```

An error is thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)

    ...
    ...
```

... which is completely valid, however I want my Java code to show that if I get a 403 Exception to instead view the 
JSON that POSTman shows, including the path, message timestamp, etc.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: use try catch block and you can do the same

Comment: Even using a try-block, the `response` becomes `null` if an error occured in the request. Thus you cannot get the JSON body containing the useful error information such as `timestamp`, `message`, `path`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will do.

```
    try {
      ResponseEntity<CorrectResponseObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, CorrectResponseObject.class);
    }catch (HttpClientErrorException exception) {
      System.out.println(exception.getStatusCode());
      System.out.println(exception.getResponseBodyAsString())
    }
```

Comment: @pvpkiran what is "SOP" in your answer?

Comment: System.out.println